# How can i display every query row into the richtextbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server

My problem is when i made a query and i wanted to load this query into richtextbox, it isn't show every results.

For example:

```
date: 22-03-2019
subject: Math 
date: 24-03-2019
subject: Grammer
```

but when i load it richtextbox i saw the first result, second result not showing.

```
conn.Open();
var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT date, subject FROM table WHERE table.id > 5", conn) 
while (reader.Read())
 {
 rtb.Text=Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "\n" + 
 (reader[1]).ToString();
 }
```

Comment: You overwrite `.Text` in the loop, `rtb.Text += ` will fix that, as would using a stringbuilder in the loop then assigning to `.Text` when your done.

Comment: @Alex: `rtb.Text +=` while better than the wrong OP code, it is recommended to use `rtb.AppendText(..)` to avoid messing up any previous formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's suppose we have a table with two columns (categoryID,CategoryName)
and we want to display each row in one line :

```
void PrintRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

in your situation you should modify your code like this :

```
conn.Open();
var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT date, subject FROM table WHERE table.id > 5", conn) 
while (reader.Read())
 {
    rtb.AppendText(reader.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString() + "\n" +reader.GetString(1));
 }
```

Comment: This still misses the `+ ` ie it still replaces the whole text in a loop and still missing using the AppendText method.

Comment: that's for you @TaW 
rtb.AppendText(reader.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString() + "\n" + 
    reader.GetString(1));